# OpenGL Calls corrupt memory

Tags: winapi, opengl-3

When I call glGetIntergerv, or any other opengl function, and step through it in gdb, upon reaching it, gdb would skip a few lines and continue stepping later in the code.

Below is the code for loading opengl, and windows. It is the only code that runs before glGetIntergerv, the first opengl call.

```
HWND window;
HDC dev_context;

HGLRC rend_context;
//Creating the Window
    char const *name = "Opengl Test";
    HINSTANCE inst = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0);
    WNDCLASS windowClass;
    DWORD dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProcedure;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance = inst;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = name;
    RegisterClass(&windowClass);

    window = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle, name, name, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, inst, NULL);

//Context
    dev_context = GetDC( window );
    std::cout << dev_context << std::endl;
    //Get pixel format
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    pfd.nSize  = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion   = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(dev_context, &pfd);
    SetPixelFormat( dev_context, nPixelFormat, &pfd );

    HGLRC temp_rend_context = wglCreateContext( dev_context );
    wglMakeCurrent( dev_context, temp_rend_context );

    HGLRC (WINAPI *wglCreateContextAttribsARB) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList) = (HGLRC (WINAPI *) (HDC hDC, HGLRC hShareContext, const int *attribList)) gl3wGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");

    const int attribs[] = { WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,  WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0, WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, /*WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB*/0, 0};

    rend_context = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(dev_context, 0, attribs);
    wglMakeCurrent(0,0);
    wglDeleteContext(temp_rend_context);
    wglMakeCurrent(dev_context, rend_context);

    gl3wInit();

    int glVersion[2] = {-1, -1};
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &glVersion[0]); //First gl call
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &glVersion[1]);
```

Below is my WndProcedure function:

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(Msg){
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
            return 0;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

I am using the gl3w library for loading the opengl functions.

Comment: what evidence do you have that the OpenGL call is corrupting memory?

Comment: While stepping in gdb, after reaching the first glGetIntegerv, it would continue down and stop at a later point in the program. Also, when I called glCreateShader inside a class function, gdb skipped down, and crashed, reporting that the this pointer was pointing at 0x1.

Comment: Why are you creating and deleting a context...  Seems kina hoky to me.

Comment: @zezba9000 The first context(for opengl 2.1) created was only to be able to use wglCreateContextAttribsARB, which creates a 3.0+ context.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a mismatch either in calling convention or parameter list, or both, which is corrupting the stack enough to screw up the call return address.

Double check that the opengl .h file(s) you're compiling with match the version of the opengl .dll(s) that you're calling. Double check that any conditional defines required for Windows are defined and enabled for the .h file. The norm for calling conventions in Win API calls is STDCALL.  If you see no calling convention on the gl functions in your .h file, be suspicious.

I vaguely recall that STDCALL and cdecl calling conventions push the parameters onto the stack in the same order (right to left) but differ in who is responsible for adjusting the stack pointer after the call.  I believe STDCALL expects the callee to pop the stack, whereas with cdecl the caller restores the stack pointer after the call returns.

What this means is if the caller is making a cdecl call but the callee is actually STDCALL, the parameters will make it into the call just fine but all hell will break loose on the return. Depending on which way the mismatch runs, either the stack pointer won't be adjusted at all or it will be over adjusted (adjusted twice).

Comment: I'm compiling with the generated gl3w.h, which uses gl3.h, directly downloaded from the Khronos website.

Comment: Ok, then double check that the defines are set appropriately to get the appropriate calling convention on the declared functions. STDCALL most likely.  You can also dig into the asm code using the disassembly view of your favorite debugger to confirm that the stack pointer is getting munged in these calls, and with a little more digging you should be able to figure out what the calling convention of the actual function / callee is expecting.

Comment: I just tried changing APIENTRY in the gl3.h to __stdcall, and also __cdecl; both of which with the same behavior in gdb.

Comment: Also, in gdb, the calls to glGetIntegerv were shown to be: mov, movl, movl, call, sub, mov, movl, movl, call, sub

Comment: +1 for this answer. I added __stdcall to APIENTRY in gl3.h and my very similar issues were fixed...after I remembered to do a clean build.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use create a GL context and use GL3 features.
Now I know this is C# but you get the picture.  There is no reason to create two GL contexts to use OpenGL3... unless im totally missing what your saying.

```
void Init(IntPtr handle, bool fullscreen, bool vSync)
{
                this.handle = handle;
                #if WINDOWS
                //Get DC
                dc = WGL.GetDC(handle);
                WGL.SwapBuffers(dc);

                //Set BackBuffer format
                WGL.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = new WGL.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR();
                WGL.ZeroPixelDescriptor(ref pfd);
                pfd.nVersion        = 1;
                pfd.dwFlags         = WGL.PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | WGL.PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | WGL.PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
                pfd.iPixelType      = (byte)WGL.PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
                pfd.cColorBits      = 24;
                pfd.cAlphaBits      = 8;
                pfd.cDepthBits      = 16;
                pfd.iLayerType      = (byte)WGL.PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
                unsafe{pfd.nSize = (ushort)sizeof(WGL.PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);}

                int pixelFormatIndex = WGL.ChoosePixelFormat(dc, ref pfd);
                if (pixelFormatIndex == 0) Debug.ThrowError("Video", "ChoosePixelFormat failed");
                if (WGL.SetPixelFormat(dc, pixelFormatIndex, ref pfd) == 0) Debug.ThrowError("Video", "Failed to set PixelFormat");

                ctx = WGL.CreateContext(dc);
                if (ctx == IntPtr.Zero) Debug.ThrowError("Video", "Failed to create GL context");
                if (WGL.MakeCurrent(dc, ctx) == 0) Debug.ThrowError("Video", "Failed to make GL context current");

                WGL.Init();//<< load 'wglSwapIntervalEXT'
                WGL.SwapInterval(vSync ? 1 : 0);
}
```

And to load GL extensions:

```
public const string DLL = "opengl32";
[DllImport(DLL, EntryPoint = "wglGetProcAddress", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr getProcAddress(string procedureName);
```